# Why Postgres DUMP data database connection lost On Amazon RDS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds

I am having Postgres database dump file of **150 GB** on Amazon EC2 instance. While dumping the data on RDS from EC2 server I am getting error.

The output of the command is as given below. It's giving error

```
1. psql connection not open    
2. connection to server was lost 
on RDS dump postgres copy command

Command Output:
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
psql:filename.sql:1396266: connection not open
psql:filename.sql:1396266: connection to server was lost
```

**Application Configuration:**

```
Ruby 1.9.3 
Rails 3
PostgreSQL 9.3
```

Please help why it is breaking while copying the data. As the connection was established and command is running. Suddenly while executing the copy command it is breaking.

**Update Findings**

Command/script that I am using to dump data the data is below:

```
psql -h instance.id.region-2.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 -U username -W -d database_name -f filename.sql
```

**Workaround for finding issues as below:**

I took `head 100 rows` and `tail 200 rows` and made `1 file` from the big `150 GB` file it converted to `56KB.` when I run this command, it's dumped successfully.

**So the file size is causing problem.** The same command is running for small size file for dumping data on RDS.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you show us the script (or just the lines of the script that cause problems)? Without the script we can not help you.

Comment: Can you show the content of `filename.sql` around line 1396266 ?

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko It's dump file and 1396266 row number contains the data row of the table. After reading the line 1396266 connection is closing with RDS. Is there any limits while dumping the data on RDS database?

Comment: +1 for 150GB db dump :D

Comment: Have you asked Amazon about this directly? My gut feeling is saving a file of 150gb is going to be a pretty intense, and getting help from the operator could ensure the fix is smooth (for example - they could dump the db & give you a link to DL)

Comment: +1 for your response and time. thanks!! And yes I think I need to ask Amazon Customer Care about this issue. May be some plan up-gradation will be required!!

Comment: Do we have a solution already? I'm suffering this error now. May someone help me out please?

Comment: I have dumped the file in the small chunks by reading the data files line by line using cron jobs

Answer (score 0):

I think your connect it's disconnect in tcp connection level. 
these is any limit in your env from your client to RDS?
like netflow control, idle session kill and so on...

Comment: thanks for response.. I am connecting RDS from EC2 instance. So connection is not breaking. But while dumping huge file in gigabytes it's failing...

Comment: you can try set tcp keepalive interval(in postgresql.conf or linux sysctl.conf), when dumping big data, there will long time idle in tcp session link, some network hardware will kill the idle sessions, set tcp keepalive will send packets between client and servers.

Comment: Hey thanks but we are not able to update RDS configuration for the postgresql. RDS will provide us just an instance. I think I need to ask Amazon Customer service.